# Download images

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to download a photo with requests.
I use this code.

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
res = session.get(url, stream=True)
with open('foo.png', "wb") as file:
    file.write(res.content)
```

The code runs without any problems, but sometimes I can not open the photo in Windows or even upload the photo to a site.

errors is: **windows photo viewer can't open this picture because the file appears to be damaged or corrupted or is too large.**

[Error in windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pOmx5.png)

What is the best solution for downloading photos correctly and completely?

Comment: Maybe the data you download is not an image. Or maybe the response contains not only raw image (maybe captcha, maybe html)

Comment: I'm sure this is a photo link.

Comment: Can you share a link that throws the error?

Comment: I can not upload in stackoverflow but you can download in this [site](https://ufile.io/bfwu21o0). 
Note that the photo may open completely for you, but you certainly can not upload the photo on some sites like Stackoverflow.